# NuGet causing Azure Pipeline issues

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines

Not every time but quite frequently I get `##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1102: Unable to find package MyPackage with version (>= 1.0.5)`
 in my Azure Pipelines builds (different packages and different versions):
[image: Pipeline error]

The package definitely exists as it had just been built a couple of minutes ago and I can see it in the Artifact Feed:
[image: Artifact feed]

Here is my pipeline:
[image: Build Step 1]
[image: Build Step 2]

The project consists of multiple packages so this is starting to get really inconvenient. If I try on different build agents I eventually get one to work but the pipelines are supposed to be more of a hands off process. As far as I can tell (or guess), Nuget is caching the index.json for the feed. The only other issues I can find related to this specifically happen in people's local environments. Is  there some way to get Nuget to properly check if packages exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet does cache what versions of a package are available on each feed for 30 minutes, so the package was published more recently than that, and that machine had already restored a different version of the package within the last 30 minutes, it will be a problem.

You could run `dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear` or `nuget.exe locals http-cache -clear` before the restore, that will delete NuGet's HTTP cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer- is this best practice or is it just unusual to push and consume a package within 30 minutes?

Comment: I don't have any data, in case you want an evidence based response. But my gut feeling is that it's very unusual to use a package within 30 minutes of it being published. There's usually a disconnect between package authors and consumers, so consumers typically won't even discover a package within 30 minutes of it being published.

Comment: For this type of thing I would publish your package as an artifact and then consume that from within your dependent pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

1.Not sure about the real cause of your issue, but if cleaning cache can help to resolve your issue, you only need to enable this option in `Restore task`.

[image]

2.Also, sometimes the `package not found error` could be related to feed permissions in Devops. Go Artifacts=>custom Feed=>Feed Settings in right corner:

[image]

Make sure your build service have access to that feed.

Comment: The Disable local cache checkbox worked for me.  Thank you!!